# How do you expand the output of a pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am currently learning python and working with CSV files. I have the following working code:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
Forbes = pd.read_csv('Forbes2000.csv') #Creates python dataframe
pd.set_option('precision', 2)
Forbes.columns=['#','Rank','Name','Country','Category','Sales','Profits','Assets','Marketvalue',]
S_df = Forbes[Forbes['Name'].str.startswith("S")].head()
```

which outputs the following:
[image]

This looks great, but I want python to print all companies that start with S in the outputted data frame. How can I get it to do this? I have tried .iloc, though I don't know if that's how one goes about expanding indexes.

```
S_df.iloc[0:10]
```

I have also tried this, as recommended by Stack Overflow question I found that seemed to be asking a similar thing.

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
```

I am getting the same output as my pictured data frame shows with or without the added .set_option code. How can I get python to print more than the default 5 pandas data frame rows?

Comment: This is the second extremely basic question you’ve asked in the span of a few hours...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas head() method is used to return the top 5 rows by default of a dataframe or series

So, Just remove .head() from last line and print S_df

Like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
Forbes = pd.read_csv('Forbes2000.csv') #Creates python dataframe
pd.set_option('precision', 2)
Forbes.columns=['#','Rank','Name','Country','Category','Sales','Profits','Assets','Marketvalue',]
S_df = Forbes[Forbes['Name'].str.startswith("S")]
print(S_df)
```

Comment: Please do mark it as the correct answer if you found it useful.